# Different header image dependant on category page

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I'm editing the twentytwelve theme of wordpress. I want to have a different header image dependant on category archive page, by the slug name. That isn't really an issue, I lack php knowledge and there is something wrong with my markup, either missing some brackets or a closing php tag, I would be grateful to see what the problem is!

This is the code below, what I'm trying to get it do is when football page is viewed it will have a different image to that page, same with baseball. Every other page will just use the header image that is used in the backend of of the twentytwelve theme options.

```
    <?php $header_image = get_header_image();

 if(    is_category( 'basball' ) )  : 

<img src="banner1.jpg" alt="baseball"/>

elseif( is_category( 'football' ) )  : 

 <img src="banner2.jpg" alt="football"/>

else ( ! empty( $header_image ) ) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( $header_image ); ?>" class="header-image" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="" /></a>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Error msg:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/topteamf/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/header.php on line 60

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not closing your PHP tags.  You have to separate your HTML and PHP.  Like this:

```
<?php $header_image = get_header_image();

if(    is_category( 'basball' ) )  : ?>

<img src="banner1.jpg" alt="baseball"/>

<?php elseif( is_category( 'football' ) )  : ?>

<img src="banner2.jpg" alt="football"/>

<?php elseif( ! empty( $header_image ) ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( $header_image ); ?>" class="header-image" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="" /></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something simple! Cheers mate.